# Auto Complete using Xamarin Forms in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a AutoComplete Text Entry using Xamarin Forms. Can anybody help me in creating a custom renderer for the auto complete text field in C#. I am using MVVM concept.

Comment: Check https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

Comment: I have checked it. It has a renderer for a listview. But I want some help in Auto complete for a entry text.

Comment: XLabs has more stuff. Check out https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/Pages/Controls/AutoCompletePage.xaml

Comment: check XLabs again, you've missed it. There is an autocomplete control there. It doesn't work with XF1.3 on iOS, it may take some time for Xamarin to update 1.3 to fix their ListView

Comment: @Nagasnree Did you find agood solution ?

Comment: Why do you need a renderer for that? A subclass of Entry should be enough that reacts on the Changed event

Comment: Do you want a control where all of the data is preloaded? Or do you want to do lazy loading ? If the latter, you will probably need to tie your control to the way you load data or put an interface in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using the following components.

An Entry field with TextChanged Event.
A ListView which to display the data set.
As a first step you can create the Entry and ListView in a StackLayout with Vertical alignment. Set ItemSource of the ListView to your data set. Add the following code in your function for TextChanged event

```
void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Site_listView.ItemsSource = vm.SiteList.Where(x => x.siteName.ToLower().Contains(siteNameEntry.Text.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();

}
```

Site_listView, siteNameEntry are the x:Name of ListView and Entry respectively

You can use ItemSelected/ItemTapped events in the list view for selecting the item from the list and assigning it to the Entry. Also you can use Focused, UnFocused events also to set the visibility of the list.